Are the meanings of the three sentences all the same?
Are the meanings of the three sentences all the same?
To teach English is hard.
Teaching English is hard.
English teaching is hard.
If not, could native speakers please explain to me the differences between them? Thank you.

(1) Not exactly wrong, but somewhat off. (2j This version sounds the most natural to me. (3) Could be interpreted to mean teaching in, rather than teaching of.

Yes, these all have the same meaning, but number two is the most natural.
